# How to put a vertical line at the right hand side of a symbol?

Tags: symbols, stacking-symbols, relation-symbols

I want to create a symbol that looks like: [image]

I recently learned that I can use `\underset{-}{\lessdot}` to get: [image]

But I need to put another vertical line at the right hand side. How can I do that?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) I am not sure if the right way to write the second symbol is `\underset{-}{\lessdot}`. You may use `\leqdot` from the MnSymbol package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it yourself by putting a `\cdot` inside `\triangleleft`. And I'd prefer
to use `\underline` rather than `\underset`

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\tdot}{\underline\triangleleft\kern-3.2pt{\cdot}\thinspace}

\begin{document}

\[
x \tdot y
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]